# Change input text to upper case using Alpine.js

Tags: javascript, alpine.js

I would like every character entered into my HTML `input` box to get uppercased. Here's the approach I am trying using the latest Alpine.js available via CDN.

```
<input 
   x-data="{myText: '' }" 
   x-text="myText" type="text" 
   @keydown="myText.toUpperCase();" 
   name="myText" 
   placeholder="Some Text"/>
```

This seems to have zero effect. What's the right way of doing solving this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a couple of things going on. First of all, you're binding to keydown but not assigning your uppercased value to any reactive property. Second is that you probably want to use `x-bind:value`.

```html
<input 
   x-data="{myText: '' }" 
   type="text" 
   @keyup="myText = $event.target.value.toUpperCase()"
   :value="myText"
   name="myText" 
   placeholder="Some Text"/>
```

Comment: This works when I modify `@change` to use `@keyup` instead. Can make this the answer if you can verify that.

Comment: Have amended, the principle is the same

Comment: odd this didn't work for me.  When pressing enter.  It submits part of the data lowercase.